# Merge branch Develop to branch Master with tag

Tags: git

I have the branches on a GIT repository:

```
develop > with 8 commits
master > with 4 commits
```

And I have one tag just created:

```
1.0.0
```

I would to merge develop branch with master branch and associate the action with tag 1.0.0.

I am trying to release to production by merging develop to master with version 1.0.0 tag.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Tags are associated with a specific commit so you can't create a new merge commit and associate it with an existing tag. You can however delete the tag and then re-create it on the new commit, or you can just use `1.0.1`